# Create nested loop to build menu in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Here i have a issue with creating nested loop with generic function and having doubt with creating menu.

Here the rows will be looks like

```
id     data             parentId
1       HEADER1             0
2       HEADER2             0
3       HEADER3             0
4       HEADER4             0
5       H1SUB1              1
6       H1SUB1              1
7       H2SUB2              2
8       H2SUB2              2
9       H1SUB1sub1          5
10      H1SUB1sub1sub1      9
```

How to bring this to menu

```
HEADER1                     HEADER2                         HEADER3                 HEADER4
    H1SUB1                      H2SUB2
    H1SUB1                      H2SUB2
        H1SUB1sub1
            H1SUB1sub1sub1
```

the code i tried is

```
var arrObj = {};
for( var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
    var row = rows[i],
    id=row.id,
    parentId = row.parentId;
    if(arrObj[parentId]){
      arrObj[parentId].items.push(row);
    } else if(parentId===0){
      arrObj[parentId] = {items=[]};    
  }
 }
```

Here I want parent Id 0 only be the HEADER in page.

Help me to create menu and how should i approach to get it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered adding a level column in the table (this will reflect the position of the item in the tree) since this will make your life soo much easier

Comment: If i add level column how much it will be easier ?

Comment: "*Here I want parent Id 0 only be the HEADER in page.*" - can you explain what this means? And could you please show the object that the JavaScript on your page receives, as well as the actual HTML that you want create for your menu?

Comment: It means which contain parent ID will be the top most header in the menu. hope you will get if you see the out put of menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a solution that you may want, I'm not sure what's the outcome you want, so I assume the results as root is an object with attribute named `items` which is an array for its childs.

```
var l = [
  {id: 1, data: 'HEADER1', parentId: 0},
  {id: 2, data: 'HEADER2', parentId: 0},
  {id: 3, data: 'HEADER3', parentId: 0},
  {id: 4, data: 'HEADER4', parentId: 0},
  {id: 5, data: 'H1SUB1', parentId: 1},
  {id: 6, data: 'H1SUB1',  parentId: 1},
  {id: 7, data: 'H2SUB2', parentId: 2},
  {id: 8, data: 'H2SUB2', parentId: 2},
  {id: 9, data: 'H1SUB1sub1', parentId: 5},
  {id: 10, data: 'H1SUB1sub1sub1', parentId: 9},
];

var getList = function(list) {


var result = {items: []},length = list.length;

   // Use object to create a hash of objects.
  var tmpStore = {}
  var i, item, id, pId;
  for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    item = list[i];
    id = item.id;
    tmpStore[id] = item;
    pId = parseInt(item.parentId, 10);
    // If its pId is 0, then Added it to result's items, otherwise, find target
    // in list, and put to its item attribute(if no such attr, create it)
    if (pId === 0) {
      result.items.push(item);
    } else {
      if (typeof tmpStore[pId].items === 'undefined') {
        tmpStore[pId].items = [];
      }
      tmpStore[pId].items.push(item);
    }
  }

  return result;
};
```

Edit: Change to object hashmapping.

Comment: The output is different. I guess its not the one am looking for.but thanks anyways .https://jsfiddle.net/oyt4j0x3/

Comment: @chan I'm really sorry that I missed something, now I edit to a correct version, with the edit comments, maybe you can take another try.

Comment: P.S: This piece of code is highly depends on the input data's format, its just like a pseudo code, you may have to change this code to adapt to your real data.

Comment: Its awesome. Working how am expecting.. Thanks

Comment: Why its not working here.http://jsfiddle.net/htu2r62d/

Comment: Because its id is not starting at 1, which do not met the array-ver's assumption, I've changed my answer and you [jsfiddle show case](http://jsfiddle.net/htu2r62d/5/), take a look.